# having an array of _ids, how can I remove the contained occurrences of these _ids that are in a subarray?

Tags: mongodb

I have an array with the `_id` that I want to remove

```
let array_id=[{"_id":"5fbc7cc705253c2da48209fe"},{"_id":"5fbc7cc705253c2da48209fe2"},{"_id":"5fbc7cc705253c2da48209f3"}]
```

this is my collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da482023f",
    "name": "juan",
    "problems_id": [
      {
        "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48209fe"  /**/
      },
      {
        "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48209fe2" /**/
      },
      {
        "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48209f3"  /**/
      },
      {
        "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48202eo"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da482092ua"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da232091ve4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48202fr3",
    "name": "pedro",
    "problems_id": [
      {
        "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48209fe" /**/
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

output desired:

```
[
    {
      "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da482023f",
      "name": "juan",
      "problems_id": [
  {
    "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48202eo"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da482092ua"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da232091ve4"
  }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48202fr3",
      "name": "pedro",
      "problems_id": [
       
      ]
    }
  ]
```

how can I do it? with .`remove` remove all documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [$pullAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) operator.

The update might look like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, { $pullAll: { problems_id: array_id } })
```

Comment: thanks friend, can you help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65032621/how-can-i-call-the-properties-that-are-in-another-collection-in-a-sub-array