# How can I call the properties that are in another collection in a sub Array?

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections: one called `places` and `type_places`. a `place` has associated a type of place (`type_places`) and this can have associated some objects from this(`objects` array).

```
type_places
{
  "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da482023f",
  "type_place": "office",
  "objects": [
    {
      "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48202saw",
      "name": "chair"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da4820242",
      "name": "table"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da482025f",
      "name": "desktop"
    }
  ]
}

places
{
    "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da482025f",
    "place": "Room 5",
    "type_place_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da482023f", /*"office"*/
    "type_place_objects": [
      {
        "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48202saw", /*chair*/
        "quantify": 4
      },
      {
        "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da482025f", /*desktop*/
        "quantify": 2
      }
    ]
  }
```

then I want that when I query a `place`, the query shows me the `place` that I am consulted, what kind of place it is (`type_place`) and what `objects` of that type of place it has

output desired:

```
{
  "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da482023f",
  "place": "Room 5",
  "type_place_objects": [
    {
      "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da48202saw",
      "name": "chair",
      "quantify": 4
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da482025f",
      "name": "desktop",
      "quantify": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying this but not works:

```
place.aggregate(
[
  {
    "$match": {"place":"Room 5"}
  },

  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "type_place",
      "localField": "type_place_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "type_place_objects"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id":1,
      "place":1,
      "type_place_objects": 1
    }
  }
  
])
```

how can do fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many ways, one ways is using `$lookup` as you already tried

```
db.place.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "place": "Room 5" } },
  { $unwind: "$type_place_objects"  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "type_place",
      "let": { tpo: "$type_place_objects._id" },
      "pipeline": [
        { $unwind: "$objects" },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [ "$objects._id", "$$tpo" ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "join"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "join": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$join", 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: { "type_place_objects.name": "$join.objects.name" }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      place: { $first: "$place" },
      type_place_objects: { "$addToSet": "$type_place_objects" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DP9I_HpKB3r)**

Comment: can you explain me this line please: `"join": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$join", 0]`

Comment: When we do join (lookup), it will give you an array. Using $arrayElemAt, im getting first object.

Comment: thannks genious, if you have free time  I would appreciate it if you would help me please with this, I was based on your previous answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051971/collection-a-that-has-a-foreigner-with-b-b-has-a-foreigner-with-collection-c-h

Comment: @yavg sorry for the late reply. was bit busy. It was answered