# collection A that has a foreigner with B, B has a foreigner with collection C, how can I bring a foreigner from A to collection C?(Aggregate)

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 collections:

```
    country
    {
        "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da4820425",
        "country":"USA"
    }

    city
    {
        "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da482025f",
        "city": "New York",
        "country_id":"5fbc7cc705253c2da4820425",
    }

    travel_reservation
    {
        "_id":"5fbc7cc705253c2da48202yQ"
        "name_person":"pablo rojas",
        "city_id":"5fbc7cc705253c2da482025f"
    }
```

a `country` collection, a `city` collection and a travel booking collection(`travel_booking`).
then in the travel booking collection (`travel_booking`) a person has an associated city (`city_id`).

How can I make an aggregate return a structure like the following one?, where in addition to obtaining the name of the `city`, I can also obtain the name of the `country`.

Output desired:

```
    {
        "_id":"5fbc7cc705253c2da48202yQ",
        "name_person":"pablo rojas",
        "city":{
            "_id":"5fbc7cc705253c2da482025f",
            "city":"New York"
        },
        "country":{
            "_id":"5fbc7cc705253c2da4820425",
            "country":"USA"
        }
    }
```

I have tried this:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/JVhroCubElX

Comment: so what's missing? what you wrote is fine, you need another `$lookup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$lookup` join city collection
- `$lookup` join country collection
- `$project` to show required fields, get first element from `city` and `country` using `$first`

```
db.travel_reservation.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "city",
      localField: "city_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "city"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "country",
      localField: "city.country_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "country"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name_person: 1,
      city: { $first: "$city" },
      country: { $first: "$country" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ziG5cxL0V_A)